# How to bill per email

Tags: invoices

For projects that require you to bill per emails read and written, how would you present this information to clients?

Are there any tools or services that solve this need?

Comment: What are you using for reading the emails? Does it count for junk mail received?

Comment: I'm using Gmail with IMAP support. Junk mail should be excluded.

Comment: Can you present time you spent reading/writing? Ps.what kind of a job this is?

Comment: It's for email support. Tracking time manually would be the most basic option, but I'm not sure it offers enough transparency and also it's a pain to do.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a log of the emails. Just have a document open all day and add one line per email:

```
10/03/2014 13:10: email X read 
10/03/2014 13:16: email X read / reply sent
```

Add this to your invoice. If any questions arise you can always look up the specific email in an inbox/archive/sent folder.

It's manual work but shouldn't take much time and gives your customer a complete overview of the work you do.